# C# Process "Persistence"

Tags: c#, powershell, process

I've been working on a System.Diagnostics.Process project (interractive powershell through network).
I want to be able to send a command from one host to another, so that the second runs it and sends the stdout + stderr to the first host.
The problem is, for example if i want to connect to a FTP server, list all files and get something for example, this should be done in one liner, because every time i send a command to another host, the Process start a new and no ftp connection "in this session of powershell" is present. Therefore "no persistence".

I'd like to run a powershell process on a user's instance once, redirect stdin, stdout and stderr to a variable, and from those be able to recieve command strings and send the output from that to the "main host".

P.S. All solutions i've found were just to run for every command a new instance of a Process and lose the "persistence" of that.

Comment: "because every time i send a command to another host, the Process start a new" because YOU TELL IT TO. SOmehow you seem to miss the fundamentls how to run a command line on the process and then send commands to it.

Comment: It sounds like this would work fine through a powershell remote session?  Though I'm not sure how to incorporate that in your C# program.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your goal is to re-invent PowerShell Remoting, I'd strongly suggest just using [a remote runspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/creating-remote-runspaces) instead, see this (oversimplified) example:

```cs
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Linq;

public class PersistentCommandRunner
{
  private Runspace remoteRunspace;

  public PersistentCommandRunner(string remoteMachine)
  {
    # Connect to remote machine using a runspace, save the runspace reference
    var connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("http://remoteMachine:5985/WSMan"));
    remoteRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
  }

  public IEnumerable<PSObject> RunScript(string script)
  {
    # Make sure runspace is ready to execute remote commands
    EnsureConnection();

    using(var shell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
      # Make sure our script runs in the remote runspace
      shell.Runspace = remoteRunspace;
      shell.AddScript(script);
      foreach(var result in shell.Invoke())
      {
        yield return result;
      }
    }
  }

  private void EnsureConnection()
  {
    if(remoteRunspace.RunspaceStateInfo.State != RunspaceState.Open)
    {
      if(remoteRunspace.RunspaceStateInfo.State == RunspaceState.BeforeOpen)
      {
        remoteRunspace.Open();
        return;
      }
      throw new Exception("Runspace is in an unusable state...");
    }
  }
}
```

Re-using the *same* runspace for subsequent scripts allows you to maintain state on the remote endpoint, ie.:

```bsh
var serverRunner = new PersistentCommandRunner();

# Stage variable in the remote session
serverRunner.InvokeScript(@"$remoteVariable = 123");

# Retrieve it again, should print "123"
Console.WriteLine(serverRunner.InvokeScript("$remoteVariable").First()?.Base as int)
```